# replacing brake pedal return spring on 57 chevy

Tags: brakes

How do I replace a brake pedal return spring on 57 Chevy. I can not locate the spring. Please help

Comment: Maybe it's missing and that's the problem? ;-)

Comment: The brake pedal has worked without any problems until recently. Now it does not return completely and the brake lights remain on. I have the spring that was recommended but can't locate where it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing if there has been any power brake assembly fitted and whether it was floor mounted or firewall mounted, it is difficult to be completely accurate. However, check where the pedal links to the push rod there should be a spring at the pivot point which should look like this:

[image: 55-57 Chevy brake pedal return spring]

Comment: Apparently OP has the replacement and knows what it looks like, but can't find the old one in the vehicle.

Comment: Stranger things have happened than being provided with the incorrect part. The image was to ensure clarity. It's common for springs like this to slide onto a shaft or pin (such as a pivot point).

Comment: The picture of the spring is what I have. The car does have power brakes and firewall mounted

Comment: This spring should be located at the top of the brake pedal assembly, at the pivot point. There should be a rod which attaches through the top of the pedal and through the spring itself. It might be easier to change this by taking down the whole pedal assembly (remove the rod linkage to the brake booster and disconnect the bracket which holds the pivot rod), then take the assembly apart to replace the spring.

Comment: With power brakes I would be very surprised if the spring is the total cause of your brake lights staying on.  The spring is normally just to keep the pedal from rattling.  A power boosted pedal should rise to the top without the spring.